# Function getting called twice on mouse click event

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I am calling a function which uploads the image on mouse click as:

```
<img type="file" id="uploadLogo" ng-click="triggerFileuploadClick('logoInput')" required>

<input ng-disabled="disableImageUpload" type="file" class="edit-button"  id="logoInput" title="Click to upload Logo" ngf-select="uploadFiles($files)" resetonclick="true">
```

And my controller is:

```
$scope.disableEditEmailer = function(){            
        $scope.disableImageUpload = true;            
    }
```

'disableEditEmailer()' is called on a button click

And in controller I am setting the value of `disableImageUpload` as true or false depending upon situation.

After setting this value, and clicking on image `triggerFileuploadClick()` is called twice. I am not getting why it is called twice?

Comment: Can you share your controller JS code? Problem could be there too

Comment: @urpalreloaded added controller code

Comment: looks like a bubbling (or event propagation) issue. are you calling this function somewhere else, higher in the hierarchy?

Comment: @OlegShemetov, no I am calling this on button click only.

Comment: still, just to be sure, try adding `$event.stopPropagation();` in your `ng-click` code, e.g. `ng-click="triggerFileuploadClick('logoInput'); $event.stopPropagation();"` or pass an event and stop it inside `triggerFileuploadClick()`